# How are the parameters for Geolocation API function reverseGeocodeAsync() formatted?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm following this tutorial and trying to use Location.reverseGeocodeAsync() but I don't get what the format of the parameter is supposed to be. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location/#locationreversegeocodeasynclocation

VS Code say this when I hover over the red underline: parameter of type '{ latitude: number; longitude: number; }'

but I tried having the parameters like these but still error:

```
{this.state.lat, this.state.long}  
{lat, long}   
lat, long  
{latitude: this.state.latitude, longitude: this.state.longitude}
```

(substitute lat, and long for the appropriate variable value/type

So can someone tell me how the parameter is supposed to be formatted?
I'm using this in React Native Expo Cli managed worflow.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5667 this fixed it

const coords = {latitude:position.latLng.lat(), longitude:position.latLng.lng()};
console.log("coords", coords);
this._attemptReverseGeocodeAsync(coords)